# Erro no isset() em php

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

```
<?php
       $a = isset($_GET["ano"])?$_GET["ano"]:1900;
       $i = date("Y") - $a;
       echo "Você nasceu em $a e tem $i";
?>
```

Onde estão ocorrendo os seguinte erros:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O valor do isset() '1900' não está sendo exibido e a variável $i não está sendo reconhecida. Como eu poderia ajustar esses erros?

Comment: Qual é a linha 12?

Comment: A linha 12 é o trecho : $i = date("Y") - $a;

Comment: O erro não é no ISSET, provavelmente o valor que você passou na URL, que deveria conter o ano, não contêm um valor numerico e causa o erro.

Comment: Esse é o trecho do código html onde passei no arquivo php:
<input type="number" placeholder="4 dígitos" name="ano"/>

Comment: @Willian.Cruz Repetindo, provavelmente o valor que você passou na URL, que deveria conter o ano, não contêm um valor numerico e causa o erro. Qual URL tentou acessar? PS: o erro não tem nada haver com o isset, a não ser que vocÊ tenha algum outro script antes.